# Flex XML Object not being set

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, rss

A bit new to flex and actionscripts, but I'm trying to get the following example code I modified a bit to pull and create an XML Object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:BasicLayout/>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var rssXML:XML = new XML();
        public var XML_URL:String="http://services.explorecalifornia.org/rss/tours.php";
        public var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
        public var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);            

        function loadXML():void
        {
            myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
            trace("Check");
            trace(rssXML.rss.channel.item.toString());
            xmlDisplay.text = rssXML.valueOf().toString();
        }


        function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            rssXML = XML(myLoader.data);
            trace(rssXML.toString());
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup>
    <s:Button label="Load XML Object" click="loadXML()"/>
    <s:Label id="xmlDisplay" text="Nothing"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

The URL I'm using is an RSS feed with sample data, http://services.explorecalifornia.org/rss/tours.php

The example when ran should display a button, when clicked, will set rssXML with the response xml from the URLrequest and then display it with the label.

However I keep getting blank instead. When I put a breakpoint where the trace("Check"); RSS is still a generic new simple XML object instead of the response XML I expect.

I'm not asking for a direct solution, just an explanation since there's something I'm overlooking since this is all new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you haven't called the [load()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#load%28%29) method of the `URLLoader` in your click event handler:

```
function loadXML():void
{
    myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
    myLoader.load(myXMLURL);
}
```

In addition to that, you should set the text of the `Label` in your "complete" event handler method (not in your click handler method):

```
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    rssXML = XML(myLoader.data);
    trace(rssXML.toString());
    xmlDisplay.text = rssXML.toString();

}
```

Comment: You sir are correct. I asked my instructor a while after a posted this and he told me the same thing. Example works as I intended.